# Error when trying to save image in NSUserDefaults using Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

When i try to save an image in NSUserDefaults, the app crashed with this error.

Why? Is it possible to save an image with NSUserDefaults? If not, then how do I save the image?

Image...

[image: Xcode error]

Code...

```
var image1:UIImage = image1

var save1: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

save1.setObject(Info.Image1, forKey: "Image1")       

save1.synchronize()
```

Log error...

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` isn't just a big truck you can throw anything you want onto.  It's a series of tubes which only specific types.

What you can save to `NSUserDefaults`:

- `NSData`
- `NSString`
- `NSNumber`
- `NSDate`
- `NSArray`
- `NSDictionary`

If you're trying to save anything else to `NSUserDefaults`, you typically need to archive it to an `NSData` object and store it (keeping in mind you'll have to unarchive it later when you need it back).

---

There are two ways to turn a `UIImage` object into data.  There are functions for creating a PNG representation of the image or a JPEG representation of the image.

For the PNG:

```swift
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage)
```

For the JPEG:

```swift
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0)
```

where the second argument is a `CGFloat` representing the compression quality, with `0.0` being the lowest quality and `1.0` being the highest quality.  Keep in mind that if you use JPEG, each time you compress and uncompress, if you're using anything but `1.0`, you're going to degrade the quality over time.  PNG is lossless so you won't degrade the image.

To get the image back out of the data object, there's an `init` method for `UIImage` to do this:

```
let yourImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
```

This method will work no matter how you converted the `UIImage` object to data.

In newer versions of Swift, the functions have been renamed, and reorganized, and are now invoked as:

For the PNG:

```swift
let imageData = yourImage.pngData()
```

For the JPEG:

```swift
let imageData = yourImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
```

Although Xcode will autocorrect the old versions for you

Answer (score 8):

In order to save `UIImage` in `NSUserDefaults`, you need to convert `UIImage` into `NSData` using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)` then save it in `NSUserDefaults`. And on the other side, while retrieving it on another `ViewController` (within that same application) you need to get `NSData` and then convert it into `UIImage`.

*Here i am writing small code snippet in swift to demonstrate this. I tried this in XCODE 6.4*

```
/*Code to save UIImage in NSUserDefaults on viewWillDisappear() event*/

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) 
{
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       //Get some image in image variable of type UIImage.
        var image = .... 
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
        defaults.setObject(imgData, forKey: "image")

}
/*Code to get Image and show it on imageView at viewWillAppear() event*/

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let imgData = defaults.objectForKey("image") as? NSData
    {
        if let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
        {
            //set image in UIImageView imgSignature
            self.imgSignature.image = image
            //remove cache after fetching image data
            defaults.removeObjectForKey("image")  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if let imgData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey("image")

Comment: This i have successfully tried in swift 1.0. But you can do this thing also.

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for Swift 3:

If you want to save image in UserDefault used below lines of code save and retrieve the image;

***To Save image in UserDefault:***

```
if let image = response.result.value {
            UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["key":UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)!])
            UserDefaults.standard.set(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100), forKey: "key")
        }
```

***To Retrieve the image from UserDefault and set it to ImageView:***

```
var mLogoImageView = UIImageView() 

if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "key") as? Data{
            let imageFromData = UIImage(data: imageData)
            mLogoImageView.image = imageFromData!
        }
```

Enjoy..!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 - 5

Set:

```
setImage(image: UIImage(named: "12")!)

func setImage(image : UIImage) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 100), forKey: "key")
}
```

Get

```
func getImage() -> UIImage? {
    if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "key") as? Data{
        if let imageFromData = UIImage(data: imageData){
            return imageFromData
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```