# Can I store image in array?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save photos from photo gallery in my app and after show them in collection View. Is there some way to store this image in array in UserDefaults?

Comment: Have a look at this question (and the answer..more important :)) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402415/error-when-trying-to-save-image-in-nsuserdefaults-using-swift Hope that helps

Comment: So which way is better? Store pngrepresentation is userdeflauts or use a Core Data?

Answer (score 1):

In NSUserDefaults you just must save Dictionary Objects, you must not save big amount of data.

To save big amount of data like images you should take a look to the Sandbox.

Take a look to the tutorial [How to save in Sandbox](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Core Data and/or store them locally.

see the responses in:
[Saving Picked Image to CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995955/saving-picked-image-to-coredata)

NSUserDefaults should only be used for the applications default values.