# Can't Save UIImage on UIViewController

Tags: swift

I've tried to save `UIImage` on `UIViewcontroller` named `secondViewController`, But didn't work.
Code snippet for saving image is attached.

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    cameraSession.stopRunning()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.cameraImageView.image!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

On `SecondViewController`, UIImage has been saved to cameraImageView.image,

But when check camera roll, nothing saved.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

hey I added full code to capture image using `UIImagePickerController` and also added code to import a photo from photo gallery, hope it will helpful for you

import  `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`and create a variable to assign `UIImagePickerController` `var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()`
and set `imagePicker.delegate = self.`

Create a action sheet to display options for 'Camera' and 'Photo library'.

On your button click action:

```swift
@IBAction func buttonOnClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    self.btnEdit.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    self.btnEdit.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallary()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    /*If you want work actionsheet on ipad
     then you have to use popoverPresentationController to present the actionsheet,
     otherwise app will crash on iPad */
    switch UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom {
    case .pad:
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        alert.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    default:
        break
    }

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera() {
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openGallary() {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: with my codes above, when I do it in primary viewcontroller, it works, but it doesnt work on secondary viewcontroller that i've added.

Comment: save image in a variable and send it to secondary ViewController

Comment: I've tried that, as for var, and as for user default even. but didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that I should do something about delegate?

Comment: then you can also pass image using UserDefault try it

Comment: Yes I meant that I've try that too, but didn't work... I wonder why it doesn't get saved into camera roll. Even it worked on main viewcontroller with just same code.

Comment: try to save it in UserDefault and call it in secondary ViewController with help of notification centre  ...

Comment: visit this to save image in UserDefault https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402415/error-when-trying-to-save-image-in-nsuserdefaults-using-swift

Answer (score 1):

Add Permission in your info.plist

`"Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description"`

After permission granted try to save image.

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    cameraSession.stopRunning()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.cameraImageView.image!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```